# jQuery AJAX Post not working

Tags: jquery

I'm currently learning jQuery and decided to do a little popup dialog that does AJAX Post requests. I've coded it, but it's not actually working. It sends the data, but the form works normally. I don't want it to work normally though, I'm trying to post the data on the same page in the dialog box.

Here's my code. Any help will be nice, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to WEBSITE</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#newlol {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 5000;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

#new {
  z-index: 3000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function newpopup(message){
    $('#new').show();
    $('#newlol').fadeIn(2000);
    if(message == "comment"){
      var message = $("#barney").html();
    }
    $('#newlolmessage').html(message);
    $('#searchForm').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      searchresult = $('#searchForm').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'search.php',
        data: searchresult,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          $('#newmessagelol').html(data.name);
        }
      });

      return false;

    });



    $('#newlolclose').click(function(){
      $('#new').hide();
      $('#newlol').hide();
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="newpopup('comment');">
<div id="barney" style="display: none;">
<form action="search.php" id="searchForm"><input type="text" name="sally"><br /><input type="submit"></form>
</div>
<a href="#">clickmeeee</a>
<div id="new">
<div id="newlol">
<div id="newlolmessage">
</div>
<div id="newlolclose">Click to close.</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should offer more information than "here's my code" if you expect help. What do you mean "the form works normally"?

Comment: It's changing the page, when I want it to open the page in the dialog box. It's hard for me to explain to be honest.

Comment: Are you sure you don´t have any javascript errors? It sounds like the submit event is never registered.

Comment: Your results are opening in a new page because in your `search.php` there must be some code which is forcing a new page to load and as Jon sad please provide us more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to change the button from a type='submit' to a type='button' and map the button's click event instead of the form's submit event. Just give the button an id of course. Even though you have preventDefault() in the code I'm guessing the form is being posted. You should get rid of the form action too if it's not needed (you're doing this within the javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have two forms created there and the form which is visible is not the one that has the submit event handler attached to. If you see below, `#barney` contains the form, which is then copied to `#newlolmessage`:

```
if(message == "comment"){
  var message = $("#barney").html();
}
$('#newlolmessage').html(message);
```

When you do `$('#searchForm').submit()`, it attaches the event handler to the first occurrence of the form (which is the hidden form), as specified in the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> If more than one element has been
>   assigned the same ID, queries that use
>   that ID will only select the first
>   matched element in the DOM. This
>   behavior should not be relied on,
>   however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

One solution for this is you can do something like:

```
$('#newlolmessage form').submit(...);
```

If that's what you're going to do, don't forget to also change the line:

```
searchresult = $('#searchForm').serialize();
```

into:

```
searchresult = $(this).serialize();
```